# Get Ram Information OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, hardware, ram

I need to get RAM information like in system_profiler
but I can't find any API to get this on OS X system (10.9 and higher are supported only).

Previously I got the information from the system_profiler

```
    NSTask *profilerTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
   [profilerTask setLaunchPath:@"/usr/sbin/system_profiler"];
```

And parsed it's output what what should I do if system profiler output language is not english ?

//Also it is slow as hell :(

Is there a good way to achieve the RAM hardware info 
e.g. Number of slots , Ecc ,Type ,Bank, Speed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specifically get `memory` information try using:

```
NSTask *profilerTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[profilerTask setLaunchPath:@"/usr/sbin/system_profiler"];
[profilerTask setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SPMemoryDataType",nil]];
```

By specifying the data type it should be quicker. To get a list of the available data types use:

```
$ system_profiler -listDataTypes
```

Comment: Okay That one point, but how should I parse output if it is not in English ?

Comment: i ma every user has distinct language , currently I am using    NSPipe to parse the output, how can I get output only in english ?

Comment: You would have to convert it, or use some type of localization. Maybe show an example of what the output looks like from another language.